# Raspberry pi 3B+ not booting using regulator

Tags: pi-3b+

I am using a **12V 2A** power adaptor** and to step down the voltage to 5V, using a voltage regulator [**LM2576-Adj**](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm2576-d.pdf). at the output of this regulator I do get **5.17V** enough voltage which is required by raspberry pi. But yet My **raspberry pi 3B+ is not booting**. I trying to power through the GPIO(PIN 2) of pi3B+

Comment: `I do get 5.17V` ... is that measured when the Raspberry Pi is powered on?

Comment: pin 2 is not part of GPIO ... it is a power pin ... refer to https://pinout.xyz/ .... only the pins that say GPIO are actually part of GPIO

Comment: If the Pi doesn't boot it's because the power supply is insufficient (voltage or current).  Not much we can do about that.

Comment: @jsotola when the raspberry pi is connected to it the voltage is 5.08V.  I want to attached  the another circuit on top of Pi that's why I want to power raspberry pi from its GPIO pin.

Comment: @ joan The LM2856 is capable of 3A current and gives 5.17V output to power raspberry pi

Comment: I am assuming that it works ok when connected to an approved power supply. This indicates that the software is OK and the PI is in operating order. If so then it appears you do not have enough power. Post a schematic, not a frizzy picture of your circuit as wired especially LM2576 portion. Also post technical links to each device connected to the PI and the USB ports. If you have a scope watch the power supply voltage when starting and see how much it dips. Also how much power does the additional circuit require.

Comment: This is a hopeless question if you can't tell us something beyond what's currently in your question. For example: **1.** Will your RPi boot from another power supply? **2.** What is the Pwr Supply voltage at PIN 2 when the RPi is connected? Measuring the voltage when there is no load connected isn't particularly helpful if you're trying to eliminate it as a *suspect*.